# register_taxonomy - show in admin menu, but not on post type (edit) screen

Tags: custom-taxonomy, metabox, admin-menu, user-interface

I've been trying a lot of things so far and investigated core inside out, but couldn't find a way that allows me to **add the submenu item**, but **doesn't add the meta box** for a custom taxonomy.

### The Menu item

```
// From: ~/wp-admin/menu.php
// That is the file that builds the menu and submenu entries.
// This is the part, where it adds the submenu items for taxonomies.
// This gets repeated for every (custom) post type menu entry.
$i = 15;
foreach ( get_taxonomies( array(), 'objects' ) as $tax ) {
    if ( ! $tax->show_ui || ! in_array('post', (array) $tax->object_type, true) )
        continue;

    $submenu['edit.php'][$i++] = array( esc_attr( $tax->labels->menu_name ), $tax->cap->manage_terms, 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=' . $tax->name );
}
unset($tax);
```

### The Meta Box

```
// From: ~/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php
// That is the file, that shows the content of a post type "edit" screen
// all taxonomies. Here it adds some meta boxes for taxonomies
foreach ( get_object_taxonomies($post_type) as $tax_name ) {
    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($tax_name);
    if ( ! $taxonomy->show_ui )
        continue;

    $label = $taxonomy->labels->name;

    if ( !is_taxonomy_hierarchical($tax_name) )
        add_meta_box('tagsdiv-' . $tax_name, $label, 'post_tags_meta_box', null, 'side', 'core', array( 'taxonomy' => $tax_name ));
    else
        add_meta_box($tax_name . 'div', $label, 'post_categories_meta_box', null, 'side', 'core', array( 'taxonomy' => $tax_name ));
}
```

The `public` argument seems to only affect the query. The only factor, that I can see being responsible for both, adding the menu entry, as well as the meta box, is the `show_ui` argument.

Please proof me wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I think your stuck with using `remove_meta_box`, the admin menu is a wild beast. Maybe a trac ticket is in order to add something like `show_meta => array(bunch of posts)`

Comment: @Wyck I'm not completely sure what will happen with happen with the menu with 3.5 as scribu is still working on a trac ticket "for a better structure of admin $menu". I guess it will be something like `get_current_screen();`. Maybe you want to make a starting point with an answer and get a trac ticket at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per le comment.

```
function remove_artist_meta() {
    remove_meta_box( '{taxonomy name}', 'post', 'side' );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_artist_meta' );
```

The Admin menu has been always difficult to deal with, some help here would be nice: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12718

But I think that this could be added a a parameter to `register_taxonomy`.
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21543